# Asp.net Textbox has a very small area to activate cursor

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a text box that is enabled, but almost acts like it is disabled.

It will only put the cursor in the textbox if I click on the left border of the box.  If I click in any of the other normal white space in the box, it doesn't do anything.  I have to hunt for the 'sweet spot' to get the cursor to appear and start typing.

This seemed to randomly crop up and I do not know of any settings that would relate to this behavior.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Something could be covering it up partially, try right clicking the area that you believe should select the text box, but is not and inspect the element with something like firebug or firefox's built in inspection tool.

Comment: Yep.  That was it.  I bumped it down a few lines and it works now.  I must have some overlap assigned in my css or something for that area that I can't see.  Thank you offthat!

Comment: You chose totally irrelevant tags, please pay more attention to tagging next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being covered partially by another element. Use a tool that allows you to right click and inspect an element, such as Firefox's built in inspector or firebug and that should show you the element that is in front of the textbox.